# Pros/cons of using ASP.NET Core 3 with a single paged application

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-mvc, single-page-application, aurelia, asp.net-core-3.1

To be more clear, imagine a "web application" that is split into two sites: the HTML stuff (Web), and the API stuff. My question is regarding the benefits of using ASP.NET Core 3 with the Web site there. For instance:

**Pros:**

- If you host your SPA within a Razor page, you can easily and reliably get the true root of the application to set the HTML `base` tag (Note the `~`). I personally don't know any other way to achieve that result without a backend framework.

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <base href="~/" />
  </head>
  ...
  </body>
  </html>
  ```
- `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SpaApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseSpa(...)` creates a fallback route, enabling your SPA to intelligently respond to situations like a 404. This could potentially be done with something like URL Rewrite in IIS, but that's setup I don't particularly want to do.
- The aforementioned fallback route also prevents you from needing to use a `#` in your page URLs. I don't know how to do this otherwise.
- Built in logging and diagnostic support - I find .NET Core 3's logging and diagnostics to be much more accessible than IIS's.
- It's there if/when you need it. Who can say with certainty that they'll never need a backend framework in their application? It's an easy value add in my book, so I figure it best to start with a backend framework from the start.

**Cons:**

- Using ASP.NET Core might introduce a slight performance impact?
- It's an additional setup requirement. Actually, our API is running ASP.NET Core 3. We already have to install one .NET Core 3 application (the API), so it's practically zero additional effort to install a second one (Web). And what if you publish your code to be a fully self-contained application?
- "It's a lot of files" - That's what someone I know says, so I'm including it here in fairness. But I'll admit that I just don't see it that way.
- It's another compilation step
- Not every knows .NET Core 3.
- It's another point of failure

Can you think of any pros or cons to add? Am I wrong about my assertions?

Comment: As far as I know, if you want to host your self-host asp.net core application on the IIS, you still need install the asp.net core runtime.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you comparing it to? static SPA served by, say, Nginx?

Comment: Yes, although IIS would be more applicable for most people who are running .NET stuff, I'd think.

Comment: "It's a lot of files" I noticed you don't share this argument, and indeed quite a very strange one. There should be less than hundred additional files, compared to the tens of thousands for  most of npm-based  SPA frameworks out there.... Yes, I'm looking at you, node_modules.